# How to properly determine whether an "exists" JPA Criteria Query clause returned true or false?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I don't know how to perform a JPA criteria query that returns with a boolean output.

The goal is to have a criteria query that looks like this when rendered on Oracle:

```
select 1 from dual where exists ( ... );
```

The `where exists (...)` part I performed with a subquery. I'm struggling with the external query.

The practical use of this is to determine whether that subquery in the `exists` clause returns `true` or `false`.

This is what I've written:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Object> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
query.from(Boolean.class);
query.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));

Subquery<Location> subquery = query.subquery(Location.class);
Root<Location> subRootEntity = subquery.from(Location.class);
subquery.select(subRootEntity);

Path<?> attributePath = subRootEntity.get("State");
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(attributePath, criteriaBuilder.literal("TX"));
subquery.where(predicate);
query.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));

TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
```

The last line outputs an error, stating that "*Boolean is not an entity*". I think my issue is not knowing how to express the "*from*" part of the query so that the result outputs 1 or 0/ true or false - not an entity.

I know I could retrieve any entity and then check if the list of results has size of 1.

I'm asking how to get a boolean result, both to avoid the unnecessary task of retrieving those columns and also to learn how to do it.

**Is this possible at all?**

Thanks!
Eduardo

Comment: No you can not directly do that but a common way is to check for the count of result set i.e if count is greater than zero then true else false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a select for one property (e.g. the ID) and set the max results returned to 1 so that you make sure the DB does not do more work than necessary (like counting all instances). Then your results list will either be empty (exists = false) or have one element (exists = true).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, a way to accomplish that without having the DBMS work more than necessary. Thanks!!

Answer (score 17):

Yes, this is possible.  Assuming that you have an entity corresponding to your `dual` table, you will want to use that entity class in `CriteriaQuery#from`.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Boolean> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Boolean.class);
query.from(dual.class);
query.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(true));

Subquery<Location> subquery = query.subquery(Location.class);
Root<Location> subRootEntity = subquery.from(Location.class);
subquery.select(subRootEntity);

Path<?> attributePath = subRootEntity.get("State");
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(attributePath, criteriaBuilder.literal("TX"));
subquery.where(predicate);
query.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));

TypedQuery<Boolean> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 9):

Hibernate 5 is working:

```
Subquery<Integer> subquery = query.subquery(Integer.class);
Root<Location> subRootEntity = subquery.from(Location.class);
subquery.select(criteriaBuilder.literal(1));

Path<?> attributePath = subRootEntity.get("State");
Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(attributePath, criteriaBuilder.literal("TX"));
subquery.where(predicate);
query.where(criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older question, but for anyone else looking:  How about trying to use Spring's jpa @Query annotation and a select case query (depending on your db implementation) with a method that returns a boolean. For example (MySQL):

```
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(l) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM Location l WHERE l.state=?1")
boolean locationForStateExists(String state);
```

Sometimes just using the query string in @Query can be a life saver when the named JPA or query builder methods don't quite do what you want them to.

Comment: This relies on `count()`, which is the fundamental problem.  Hibernate does not support the `exists` keyword except inside the `where` clause, which doesn't accomplish what the OP is asking.  Selecting a `count` could potentially be extremely slow (depending on the complexity of the `where` clause, presence of indexes, etc.) while an `exists` clause will fast-fail on the first occurrence.  It's really a shame JPA/Hibernate doesn't support this trivial optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum optimized and full solution for existance checking via Criteria API based on [dimo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024659/19332245) and with help of [user3158918 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43760801/19332245):

```
EntityManager em = ...;

val cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
val query = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);
val root = query.from(YourEntity.class);

val predicate = cb.equal(root.get(attribute), attributeValue);

query.select(cb.literal(1)).where(predicate);

return !em.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(1).getResultList().isEmpty();
```

I used a lombok to be clean.
This code generates SQL query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM your_entity_table WHERE your_entity_table.attribute = attributeValue LIMIT 1
```

Please post your solution, if its faster...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the the query.from(Boolean.class). It tries to create a "select object from boolean" query. If you want a boolean as return type you need to use

```
CriteriaQuery<Boolean> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Boolean.class)
```

Then query from any existing entity table to create a valid query (perhaps from the subquery's table). I don't think that create from dual works except if you managed to map the dual table.

Answer (score -2):

Is there any reason that all the logic has to be in JPA? If not, why not use SELECT COUNT and then a conditional to set the boolean?

```
Boolean exists = false;
int count = selectCountQuery();
if (count > 0) {
  exists = true;
}
```